# Does cubic equation always have analytical solution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I saw this blog : http://www-old.me.gatech.edu/energy/andy_phd/appA.htm
that in the bottom of the page about the analytical solution of cubic equation said " there are cases when this analytical solution will not work, or worse, predict incorrect roots. In such cases, an iterative solution must be used". My question is "Does cubic equation always have analytical solution ?" or "does it have a general analytical solution and where can I found this general analytical solution" ?

Comment: The roots of a cubic equation can always be found algebraically, although the particular approach that the source you linked uses might not be fully general.

Comment: Where can I find an approach that in general case finds the roots algebraically ?

Comment: Wikipedia gives several approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [Cardano's formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula), which gives you an exact solution.

Comment: how can I find an exact reference that writes Cardano's formula in it ? Because I must refer to an exact reference in my report.

Comment: Check the "Sources" section in the bottom of the link.